# Why are Parenthesis not added to CExpression in Package SymbolicC?

Tags: code-generation

The documentation of `SymbolicC`, more specifically of `COperator`, states that Parentheses are added as necessary together with the following example:

```
In[1]:= Needs["SymbolicC`"]

In[2]:= COperator[Times, {COperator[Plus, {a, b}], c}] // ToCCodeString

Out[2]= "(a + b) * c"
```

I expected the same result, when I used CExpression to create the `a+b`-part of the expression:

```
In[3]:= COperator[Times, {CExpression[a + b], c}] // ToCCodeString

Out[3]= "a + b * c"
```

However, the required parentheses were not added. They may be added explicitly using `CParentheses`:

```
In[4]:= COperator[Times, {CParentheses@CExpression[a + b], c}] // ToCCodeString

Out[4]= "(a + b) * c"
```

This feels wrong to me. I expected all of `Out[2]`, `Out[3]` and `Out[4]` to be the same.

Is this a bug?

Comment: By the way, this has been tested with Mathematica 10.1.0.0 on Linux x64.

Comment: I suspect that `COperator` doesn't "see" within the expression generated by `CExpression`, so it doesn't realized that it needs to be wrapped in parentheses.